# Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/snapd_2.32.9_amd64.deb

Tags: package-management, updates, dpkg, snap

complete noob here, trying to update from 16.04 to 18.04 - but I'm facing an error with my package manager.
Even running `sudo apt-get install -f` (after going through a few suggestions I found) results in this error:

> Errors were encountered while processing:
>    /var/cache/apt/archives/snapd_2.32.9_amd64.deb
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Any clues on what I can do to fix this?

Thank you!

edit - adding full output of `sudo apt-get install -f`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 linux-headers-4.13.0-36 linux-headers-4.13.0-36-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-117 linux-headers-4.4.0-117-generic
  linux-headers-generic-lts-xenial linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-117-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-36-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-117-generic linux-image-generic-lts-xenial
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  snapd
The following packages will be upgraded:
  snapd
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 147 not upgraded.
35 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/14,2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 2 478 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 321112 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../snapd_2.33~14.04_amd64.deb ...
Failed to stop snapd.autoimport.service: Unit snapd.autoimport.service not loaded.
Failed to stop snapd.socket: Unit snapd.socket not loaded.
Failed to stop snapd.service: Unit snapd.service not loaded.
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Failed to stop snapd.autoimport.service: Unit snapd.autoimport.service not loaded.
Failed to stop snapd.socket: Unit snapd.socket not loaded.
Failed to stop snapd.service: Unit snapd.service not loaded.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/snapd_2.33~14.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/snapd_2.33~14.04_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: For error code 1 handling, we need to know if its post processing or preprocessing. Paste more log information.

Comment: Thanks! Where can I find that? Should I simply paste the /var/crash output? The crash report is giving me this: package snapd 2.31.2-14.04 failed to install/upgrade:subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 5

Comment: Trying to upgrade gives me this: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-core-launcher : Depends: snapd (= 2.33~14.04) but 2.31.2~14.04 is installed. E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

Comment: please edit your post to paste all the output of `sudo apt-get install -f` formatted with {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to remove `ubuntu-core-launcher` as I don't believe it's required anymore.

```
sudo apt remove ubuntu-core-launcher
```

Which may progress your upgrades further.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt remove ubuntu-core-launcher

also creates the following error

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'ubuntu-core-launcher' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 default-jdk : Depends: openjdk-11-jdk but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

any help plz